# SubmitChanges does not update foreign key to the database

Tags: vb.net, linq, silverlight, windows-phone

My problem occurs in a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight VB application. The CatDataContext defines a table Books with items Title and a foreign key _seriesID, with belongs to a table Series.

```
   <Table()>
    Public Class Series
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
        ' Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
        Private _seriesID As Integer

        <Column(IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, DbType:="INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull:=False,
            AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert)>
        Public Property SeriesID() As Integer
            Get
                Return _seriesID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                If _seriesID <> value Then
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("SeriesID")
                    _seriesID = value
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("SeriesID")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        ' Define name: private field, public property, and database column.
        Private _Name As String
        <Column()>
        Public Property Name() As String
            Get
                Return _Name
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If _Name <> value Then
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Name")
                    _Name = value
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Name")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        ' Used to notify that a property changed
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanging Members"

        Public Event PropertyChanging As PropertyChangingEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging

        ' Used to notify that a property is about to change
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanging(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanging(Me, New PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class

    <Table()>
    Public Class Book
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging

        ' Define ID: private field, public property, and database column.
        Private _bookID As Integer
        <Column(IsPrimaryKey:=True, IsDbGenerated:=True, DbType:="INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull:=False,
            AutoSync:=AutoSync.OnInsert)>
        Public Property BookID() As Integer
            Get
                Return _bookID
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                If _bookID <> value Then
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("BookID")
                    _bookID = value
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("BookID")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        ' Define title: private field, public property, and database column.
        Private _title As String
        <Column()>
        Public Property Title() As String
            Get
                Return _title
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If _title <> value Then
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Title")
                    _title = value
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Title")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        ' Internal column for the associated series ID value.
        <Column()>
        Friend _seriesID As Integer
        Private _series As EntityRef(Of Series)
        <Association(Storage:="_series", ThisKey:="_seriesID", OtherKey:="SeriesID")>
        Public Property BookSeries() As Series
            Get
                Return _series.Entity
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Series)
                NotifyPropertyChanging("BookSeries")
                _series.Entity = value
                If value IsNot Nothing Then
                    _seriesID = value.SeriesID
                End If
                NotifyPropertyChanged("BookSeries")
            End Set
        End Property

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"

        Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements NotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

        ' Used to notify that a property changed
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub

#End Region

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanging Members"

        Public Event PropertyChanging As PropertyChangingEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanging.PropertyChanging

        ' Used to notify that a property is about to change
        Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanging(ByVal propertyName As String)
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanging(Me, New PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName))
        End Sub

#End Region
```

Updating of the field Title alone, or the fields Title and _seriesID works fine. However when I only change the _seriesID then no update of the underlying database is done. In this case .GetModifiedMembers shows no modifications.

A reference to a demo project showing this problem is given here: [demo project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=93F3DDC39664C29A!16622&authkey=!AJyx4UquFkIGlP4&ithint=file%2Czip).

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Please show the relevant code in your question, not in a separate link. And pay due attention to code formatting and paragraphing.

Comment: Did you add `Friend _seriesID` yourself?

Comment: I used this in analogy to the Microsft example "How to create a local database app with MVVM for Windows Phone 8".

Comment: Does that answer my question?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you should reformulated your question, but I think the simple answer to your question is "yes". Furthermore changing 'Friend"in "Private" makes _seriesID invisible in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 0):

`_seriesID` (in `Book`) is just a *member variable*. You can set it from outside `Book` because it is `Friend`, but further nothing happens.

`Title`, on the other hand, is a *property* that fires `NotifyPropertyChanged`. That means that the context is notified that the `Book` object has been modified if you change `Title`.

So if you change `_seriesID` *and* `Title`, the `Book` object is marked as modified and saved, along with the changed value of `_seriesID`. But if you change `_seriesID` alone, the object remains 'unchanged'.

I think this is generated code (LINQ-to-SQL? I don't really recognize it) and you shouldn't modify it manually. If you want `_seriesID` to be changed, you have to set `BookSeries`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort, Gert. I will explore this further and let you know on this platform.

Comment: Again, I was very glad with your answer explaining why _seriesID don't fire the NotifyPropertyChanged. I'm not sure how to ues yoyr suggestion. BookSeries is the other table which I don't want to change. I just want that _seriesID in Books refers to another row in the Bookseries table.

Comment: I'm left now with the possibilities: 1)Each time _seriesID is changes, also Title will be changed by adding a character, and after the SaveChangesToDB the Title will be restored (which I use now without problems) 2) change in the CatDataContext the definition of _seriesID into a public property (and not a key) 3) Explore if a join of the two tables can be used. I could not find until now useful info on this subject for VB  applications.

Comment: You only have to do something like `book.BookSeries = series`, where `series` is a `BookSeries` object. That doesn't modify the `BookSeries` object itself.

Comment: Your answer is so simple that I wondered why I coudn't figure it out in the last two weeks. Your answer was a big help, it worked perfectly and also helped me in my understanding of these topics. Thanks very much for your effort and succesful help